# How to change root password for PostgreSql phpPgAdmin?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql

What is the simplest way to change `root` password for `PostgreSql phpPgAdmin` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# sudo su - postgres
# psql -d template1
template1=# ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new password';
# service postgresql restart
```

Comment: Please add explanation for the commands :)

Answer (score 1):

```
• sudo su - postgres
• psql
• \password postgres
• TYPE THE POSTGRES PASSWORD
• \q
• exit
```